# I can not edit and submit form from jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this code:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.over').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).html($('<form/>', {
            action: 'edit.php',
            method: 'POST'
        }).append($('<input/>', {
            type: 'text',
            name: 'name',
            value: $(this).text()
        })));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text over" id="1">TEXT</div>
```

So, when the mouse is over, the input appears, but empty and I can not edit to send the form.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `$(this).text()` it's already too late. The element HTML has already changed.

Use the `append:` instead of `.append(`  in order grab the `$(this).text()` at `form` **creation time**!
***Important***: Notice also the use of `.one()` and `mouseenter` (instead of mouseover)

```js
$('.over').one("mouseenter", function(){

  $(this).html(
    $('<form/>', {
      action: 'edit.php',
      method: 'POST',
      append: $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'name',
        value: $(this).text()
      })
    })
  );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text over" id="1">TEXT</div>
```

BTW...

[image: Difference between Mouseover and mouseenter]

Answer (score 4):

1. you're using `.html()` which replaces all the contents, so by the time you call `value: $(this).text()`, it's already been replaced with a form.
2. you seemingly can't edit it because each time you click on it with the mouse, it triggers the event all over again. you can edit it if you <kbd>tab</kbd> to the input